# Detect truncation of responseText whenever XMLHttpRequest is interrupted?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, xmlhttprequest, abort

Right now, I have

```
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if(request.readyState != 4) return
  if(request.status == 200) {
     // present request.responseText
  } // else present error
}
```

However, there is a possibility that, for large response bodies, there will be a partial success.
There are two situations I see where this could happen:

1. The TCP socket is terminated, perhaps due to unstable network conditions.
2. I call `request.abort()` when a timeout period has expired.

In either situation, it is *possible* to have already received a partial response, in which case I think that `request.status` would be set, and `request.responseText` would provide truncated content.

How can my `onreadystatechange` function distinguish between a successful (complete) response, or a response that was interrupted?

(With JSON this is easy to detect, because `JSON.parse` would throw an error if the response was truncated, but for HTML or plain text, I'm looking for a more official indicator.)

Comment: i thought `request.readyState==4` meant "done"... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState, but you're right about the other two props (status and responseText)

Comment: `request.readyState == 4` still occurs after `request.abort()`, as well as after total failure. (e.g. no internet) I assume it also occurs after incomplete response as well. (e.g. spotty internet)

Comment: abort()ing implies it's "done" as well. fwiw, i've never seen a response hit 4 and not be done, even on large/slow URLs. you can compare the `content-length` header (if avail) to `responseText.length` other that that, there's not much the interface offers to inspect.

Comment: If it was just about `abort()` (#2) then I wouldn't be asking. I'm also interested in #1, (incomplete response e.g. spotty internet) although it's rare, it is still possible.

Comment: do you know if the newer `loadend` event is better in that respect? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/loadend (it seems to cover the bases)

Comment: It appears to provide a more convenient way to compare `Content-Length`, but other than that it seems similar.

Comment: have you looked into `abort` and `error` events of XMLHttpRequest? `onreadystatechange` is "old school" XHR

Comment: `error` seems like it might work. I'd have to test it though.

Comment: `loadend` fires after `error`, so why bother subscribing extra callbacks?